# Most efficient way to optimize based on gpu type?

Tags: directx9

So, I'm writing an optimization button that should optimize a game based on the type of hardware the user has. I know I can use d3dadapter_identifier9 to achieve this, but what would be the most efficient way of actually implementing it? Not sure whether i should check based on deviceid, name, etc. was hoping someone could give me a couple tips for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may well depend on what kind of bottleneck you've identified in your game that you want to optimize for. Which devices are you finding are performing below your targets, on what kinds of workloads?

Comment: Well, I find many low-lowmid range gpu's are having issues with the water reflections, lightmaps, and quality of models. SInce all maps use lightmapping, and about 20% of the maps have water, it can be a big issue for players. The model quality only becomes an issue on lower end systems if there's several people playing at one time. My idea was (idk if devid's work this way) to use if statements to check if the users devid fell between certain values, and based on that set their lightmap on/off, water quality on low/med/high/ultra, and the same with model quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not actually perform some frames of rendering and time it. If it is below your target speed turn off some features and try again. Keep doing this until performance is within your target. To hide it from the player just draw fullscreen quad overtop or setup offscreen rendertarget and never present it.
As commenters note you will want to allow the user to override the setting somehow as some may want to have better visuals regardless of performance impact or vice versa.

Comment: Just make sure, that you let the players decide otherwise. Some players prefer quality over FPS(Not like I understand it) and some FPS over quality.

Answer (score 2):

Direct3D 9 and prior optimization is quite challenging. You have to handle the 'sea of caps' where specific hardware and drivers can remove almost any caps bit and expect apps to handle it when in fact few do. This really complicates the 'feature fallback' problem.

With Direct3D 10 or later, the 'sea of caps' problem is greatly reduced by the [Direct3D hardware feature level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx) where each new feature level is a superset of the older ones. You pick a minimum feature level for your game, perhaps scale up to a specific higher feature level or two, and not worry that individual hardware caps will disappear at these higher levels.

With all versions of Direct3D, you still have to scale based on performance. A Feature Level 11.1 device is required to support hardware tessellation, DirectCompute, and a whole slew of other features including everything a Feature Level 11.0 device supports. This says nothing with how fast the hardware is at doing any of this. For example, the WARP software device supports Feature Level 11.1 but is much slower than dedicated video hardware.

The typical solution here is to have some basic assumption of 'good enough' settings and allowing users to tweak settings as desired. Ideally you can do a benchmark to make the initial settings more accurate, but it's still a pretty open ended problem. Developers use display resolution scaling, level-of-detail artwork, turn on and off individual features, etc. to try to provide this flexibly.

This is the main way that consoles are easier to target than PC because you the developer can do all the tuning in development and know the user's machine is basically the same. This process on PCs is complicated by aggressive power management and heterogeneous GPUs (i.e. the laptop/tablet has an integrated part, but if you dock it or plug it in it can use a dedicated GPU).

The device id (`DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.VendorId` / `DeviceId` or `D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9.VendorId` / `DeviceId`) is typically only used to generate a warning--like I do in [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx)--or as a workaround for a specific driver bug. It's not a safe way to handle feature detection or to do performance scaling.